# Find max number in cell array of Strings (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, cell-array

If I have a cell array M that consist of strings (some of them are strings contain words, other contain numbers)

```
M={'r' '2'  '17'
   '2' 's'  '15'
   '5' '10' 'rr'
   }
```

How can I get the maximum number in second column, so the answer will be 10 ?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer Rody has given, please consider to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fact that `str2double` converts non-numeric strings to `NaN`, which `max()` ignores by default:

```
mx = max( str2double(M(:,2)) )
```

To compute the mean, MATLAB's default behavior is to *in*clude `NaN`, so you'll have to tell it to behave otherwise:

```
mn = mean( str2double(M(:,2)), 'omitnan')
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the average of the column also ?? Avg= (2+10)/2 @https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085062/rody-oldenhuis

Comment: Commenting from phone so untested but this should work `M=str2double(M(:,2))` then `avg=mean(M(~isnan(M(:))))`